# Insert Function will not work called inside of another function?

Tags: postgresql

I have the a bizarre thing happening. I created an insert function in PostgreSQL (v 9.1.10). When I call the function directly from the PGSQL command line, it works fine.

However, when I call the insert function from another function it will not perform the insert. The most frustrating part is it doesn't even return an error. It's as if it's simply skipping the insert statement, but ONLY if it's being called from another function. Called directly, it works like a charm. I've checked the variables being passed in (from the function) there doesn't seem to be any problem there, in fact I can use "raise notice" to display the parameters I pass in for the insert statement. Very frustrating. I've scoured the board for  ideas...but coming up short. Here is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO insert_table (adp_batch_id, adp_account_id, week_start_date, week_end_date, created_date, modified_date, created_by, modified_by)
  SELECT i_insert_batch_id
        , adpa.adp_account_id
        , d_week_begin_date::timestamp
        , d_week_end_date::timestamp
        , now()::timestamp as created_date
        , now()::timestamp as modified_date
        , '9999999'::bigint as created_by
        , '9999999'::bigint as modified_by
  FROM adp_accounts adpa WHERE adpa.code = cAccount_name;
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you check if you are rollingback instead of commit at the end of the process? Post both functions here, so we can see what you're doing...

Comment: I can't take the risk of being lynched for posting too much code (i.e. work related). lol... However, I'm going to try a simpler route and see if I have any luck. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with type casting. Being new to PGSQL it's been one of my biggest challenges.

Comment: If the select statement in there is returning nada, it won't insert anything. You need to figure out why the select isn't returning anything. And under no circumstance will you get lynched for posting the code needed to reproduce the problem — unless, of course, you post your app's entire code instead of reducing it to "just what's needed to make it not work".

Comment: Thanks Denis! Apparently, there was a bigger issue. Having a heavy MSSQL background, I'm still getting used to the behavior of PGSQL. It turns out the error was in another function. What I did not know is if I have an error at all, none of the DML statements are committed. So the insert statement was indeed working. However an error after the insert statement prevented the insert from being committed (if that makes sense). Once I resolved that error. The insert statement worked!

Comment: The error turned out to be, I called one of my functions which returned a void with a select statement:
SELECT myfunction()
However since it did not return a value it caused the error that prevented my previous insert statement from being commited. However once I updated it to:
PERFORM myfunction()
And everything worked. :-)